# C# - Reload tabs from Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs, master-pages

I have a FromDate and ToDate textboxes and a submit button in my Master page. I have 4 tabs with links for 4 different URLs displaying various reports.

Now on change of Dates and click of submit button, can I update/reload the reports (tabs) based on date change?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest moving your from-to dates and submit button to a user control. You can then put that on each report, expose and wire up changed events on your control and expose properties for your from-to date textboxes to pop into your report.

In Visual Studio create a user control. If you are unsure how to do this try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) link.

Populate the user control with your text boxes. Something like this:

```
<div>

<asp:Label ID="FromDateLabel" Text="From:" AssociatedControlID="FromDateTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="FromDateTextBox" runat="server" />

<asp:Label ID="ToDateLabel" Text="To:" AssociatedControlID="ToDateTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="ToDateTextBox" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" Text="Update" runat="server" 
        onclick="UpdateButton_Click" />

</div>
```

And the code behind for that control. You'll need to expose an event and the two properties, which might look like this:

```
public partial class ReportDateControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler UpdateReport;
    public string FromDate
    {
        get { return this.FromDateTextBox.Text; }
        set { this.FromDateTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
    public string ToDate
    {
        get { return this.ToDateTextBox.Text; }
        set { this.ToDateTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UpdateReport != null)
        {
            UpdateReport(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In your .aspx page you'll need to register the control, which might go something like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ReportDateControl.ascx" TagPrefix="myapp" TagName="ReportDateControl" %>
```

And then actually put it on the page:

```
<myapp:ReportDateControl id="ReportDateControl" 
                         runat="server" 
                         OnUpdateReport="ReportDateControl_UpdateReport" />
```

And then wire up the code behind to handle the update events:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ReportDateControl_UpdateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.ReportDateControl control = (Controls.ReportDateControl)sender;

        string fromDate = control.FromDate;
        string toDate = control.ToDate;

    }
}
```

Change the names and formatting where appropriate, but this should give you a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, how do I move them to a User Control? Can you give me an example please..

Comment: Thanks a ton Jay, It totally worked and you made my day !! What if I need to add some more things to that user control?? Say a drop down.. or a list box?

Comment: You can add whatever you like to a user control. This can be a pitfall however. A user control should be simple and have a single purpose, otherwise its chances for reuse diminish; just as a general rule. Add the control just like to a regular page, then expose the important properties like what was done here for the textboxes.

Comment: Oh I already did that. I'm able to access the selected values.. but how to access the dropdown directly? Should I use a FindControl? It ain't working !

Comment: You can always expose the control itself through a property on the control, make it readonly however.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can expose the Date controls from the master page and access them through the Page.Master property. You'll need to cast to the specific type of your master page to get at it's properties.